Nuxt, .env and plain .js files
This relates to an app running Nuxt 3.12.4.
I need to set a variable in a .env file, but that variable is needed in a plain .js file within the application's /lib. This, in nuxt.config.js, should make the variable available in .vue files:
 publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },

But, it's still undefined in the .js file if I look for it with process.env and the application hangs if I try this.$config.
I tried installing dotenv and doing:
require('dotenv').config();

In the relevant .js file, but still no luck.
The next thing I'd look for is an index.js in which to require dotenv, but that file seems to be automatically generated.
Any ideas on how I might make this work?
The purpose, BTW, is to have a different URL when running on development hosts vs. production.

The only workaround I could find was to produce an env.js file containing:
export function baseURL() {
    return 'http://localhost:5000/api'
}

Then, the plain Javascript (not vue/nuxt) file can have this:
let BASE_URL;
try {
    const env = require('../../env.js');
    BASE_URL = env.baseURL() || 'https://default/api';
}
catch {
    BASE_URL = 'https://default/api';
}
Object.freeze(BASE_URL);

This achieves the goal of allowing developers to run the application on their laptops with a correct localhost URL without having to modify the lib/restApiLibrary.js file in question each time they do some work.

You can set env vars from shell script for example. Why is that not working? Solution you posted is very unconventional and not recommended. I already have my projects where I am using env var provided by shell script and it works fine.

Doesn't work for me in Netlify or local environment; the values are null when accessed vis process.env within the plan-javascript-not-vue file. I'm damned if I know why.

Using ENV variables directly in prod is considered an anti-pattern in nuxt.
Nuxt won't intentionally allow that: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env#production
General flow is:
.env file is loaded and injected into runtimeConfig, which is then accessible throughout the app using useNuxtApp().runtimeConfig;
Example:
runtimeConfig: {
  db: {
    url: "",
  },
  public: {
    name: "",
  }
}

Can be replaced automatically during runtime using
NUXT_DB_URL="...."
NUXT_PUBLIC_NAME="...."

Remember, you cannot access it outside of nuxtApp's context. So if that's the case, reply with exact use-case so I can help find workaround.
Now, only the variables present under runtimeConfig.public scope are accessible in client-side for safety. Also, none of the env variable would be accessible on client-side (which would lead to side-effects, thus the anti-pattern).

Thanks. Strange that it should be considered an anti-pattern. The previous dev working on this got around it by hard-coding the URL within the .js file.
Anyway, in this application there's a .js library which makes some API calls. I'd like to be able to define development and production URLs differently.

My bad, using env vars is not anti-pattern, using .env file is. You can still set env vars from other medium. Go through the link.

The link didn't help; I'm afraid. It's not a vue file in which I need to set the env vars so using Nuxt's runtimineConfig won't do the trick.

you didn't get the point. Nuxt just won't read env file. You can still set env vars using other ways such as from a shell script, or use option provided by your deployment provider, eg, Vercel.

I very much got the point, and asking how to work around the fact that "Nuxt just won't read env file" and that .js files don't see Nuxt's variables. See my answer for one solution.

You can access the env vars like so: process.env.BASE_URL. This will work in, for example, server routes.
publicRuntimeConfig doesn't exist, use this pattern instead:
runtimeConfig: {
  PRIVATE_KEY: "12345",
  public: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}

Then, in a Vue component you can do something like this:
const BASE_URL = useRuntimeConfig().public.BASE_URL

Read more:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config


This only appears to work in .vue files, but I'm using a .js file, unfortunately.

you can access runtime config in js files too! Please update with better reproduction so that I can assist you further.

I'm afraid there's nothing more I can add.
